# What is the difference between both the sample?

Tags: javascript, recursion, merge, mergesort

Sample 1:

```
function mergesort(arr){
    if (arr.length > 1){
        let mid = parseInt(arr.length/2);
        let left = arr.slice(0,mid);
        let right = arr.slice(mid);
        mergesort(left);
        mergesort(right);  
        return merge(left,right);
    }
    else return arr;
}
```

Sample 2:

```
function mergesort(arr){
    if (arr.length > 1){
        let mid = parseInt(arr.length/2);
        let left = mergesort(arr.slice(0,mid));
        let right = mergesort(arr.slice(mid));   
        return merge(left,right);
    }
    else return arr;
}
```

Merge function:

```
function merge(left, right){
    let leftIdx = 0, rightIdx = 0; 
    const result = [];
    while (leftIdx < left.length && rightIdx < right.length){
        if (left[leftIdx] < right[rightIdx]){
            result.push(left[leftIdx++])
        }
        else{
            result.push(right[rightIdx++])
        }
    }
    let res = [...result, ...left.slice(leftIdx), ...right.slice(rightIdx)];
    return res;
```

Sample 2 is giving the correct output but sample 1 is not. Can you explain the difference between both samples?

```
let arr = [5, 3, 7, 2, 9, 12, 4];
```

Applying sample 1 on arr gives [2, 5, 3, 7, 9, 12, 4] as output that is obviously incorrect.

Comment: In sample 1, a call to `mergesort(left)` does not affect the `left` array, because the function doesn't perform any mutation on the input. In sample 2, you can see that the result of `mergesort(arr.slice(0,mid))` is assigned to `left`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change these two lines

```
mergesort(left);
mergesort(right);
```

to

```
left = mergesort(left);
right = mergesort(right);
```

Otherwise you are continuing to work with the unsorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your first code sample does not work because you did not assign the output of `mergesort` to a new variable.

Try it like this instead:

```js
function mergesort(arr){
    if (arr.length > 1){
        let mid = parseInt(arr.length/2);
        let left = arr.slice(0,mid);
        let right = arr.slice(mid);
        left = mergesort(left);
        right = mergesort(right);  
        return merge(left,right);
    }
    else return arr;
}
```